# Send GSD Command in JSON to Zebra Printer

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, zpl, zpl-ii

Trying to send commands (not labels) to Zebra printers using Python.

On page 574 of the [documentation](https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/zpl/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) it shows:
[image]

Here's my code:

```
mysocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)          
host= "192.168.100.245" # verified IP address of Zebra printer
port = 9100
mysocket.connect((host, port)) 
name_string= '''"sgd.name":null'''
my_string= f'''{{}}{{{name_string}}}'''
x = json.dumps(obj=my_string)
mysocket.sendall(bytes(x,encoding="utf-8"))
data= mysocket.recv(1024)
print(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

The printer responds to pings and other non-JSON Zebra commands sent to it (i.e. `mysocket.send(b"~hs")`).  However, with the code above I wait for a long time and no response returns from the printer.

Tried multiple variations of the JSON formatting, what should I try next?

Per @bruan comment I tried the following variations but did not work:

`my_string= '''"sgd.name":null"'''`

`my_string= '''{}{"sgd.name":null}'''`

Comment: It looks like you create the JSON/command manually, then dump it into JSON one more time. What you send now is `'"{}{\\"sgd.name\\":null}"'`. I think you should send `my_string` as command. That said, better create JSON used in the command properly

Comment: @buran tried two variations based on your feedback, no success.

Comment: but did you remove the `x = json.dumps(obj=my_string)` line? Second one looks right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create the JSON/command manually, then dump it into JSON one more time. What you send now is `'"{}{\\"sgd.name\\":null}"'`, i.e. the string `"{}{\\"sgd.name\\":null}"`
Also, as I said in the comments, better don't create JSON manually. Use `json` module and it will be easier to expand the `query` dict and get multiple values at once if needed.

```
import json

# some lines skipped for brevity
query = {'sgd.name': None}
command = f'{{}}{json.dumps(query)}' # {}{"sgd.name": null}
mysocket.sendall(bytes(command, encoding="utf-8"))
```